# Javascript is there a way to get the index of an array when using functional programming?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript, I want to use functional programming methods (like filter, and map) to transform an array and want to include the array index in the result.

For example, I have an array myArray, I filter it, and format each item in the array, and then join the results together into one large string.
This works except that it doesn't include the array index.

```
 myArray.filter(myFilterFunction).map(prettyPrinterFunction).join(sep);
```

The following code illustrates this.  You can copy/paste it into node to experiment.

```
class Item {
    constructor(itemNumber){
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }
    toString(){
        return "Item #" + this.itemNumber;
    }
}

function myFilter(anItem){
    return anItem.itemNumber > 3;
}

function myFormatter(anItem){
    return anItem.toString();
}

// This function does what I want
function formatArray(theArray, theFilter, theFormatter, sep = "\n"){
    var output = "";
    var newLine = "";
    for(ii = 0; ii < listOfObjects.length; ii++){
        if (myFilter(listOfObjects[ii])){
            output += newLine + ii + " " + theFormatter(listOfObjects[ii]);
        }
        newLine = sep;
    }
    return output;
}

var listOfObjects = [];
listOfObjects.push(new Item(5));
listOfObjects.push(new Item(4));
listOfObjects.push(new Item(1));
listOfObjects.push(new Item(8));

var output = formatArray(listOfObjects, myFilter, myFormatter);

console.log(output);
```

This outputs the index of the array followed by the formatted result, and *this is the desired output*.

```
0 Item #5
1 Item #4
3 Item #8
```

The following functional style:

```
var output = listOfObjects.filter(myFilter).map(myFormatter).join("\n");
console.log(output);

Item #5
Item #4
Item #8
```

is almost exactly what I want but it doesn't have the array index associated with the item.

**What change is needed in order to get the array index in the output/results?**

Comment: Refer to the relevant docs: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) supply their callbacks with three arguments: the **element**, its **index** and the original **array**.

Comment: a side note, your `ii` wasn't declared and its prolly leaking to global

Comment: le_m, the docs say "the array" being processed, not the "original array".  Do you have a pointer to an example that shows what you mean?  I might be mis-understanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this was a fun one.  Here's runable [code](https://runkit.com/arthur/functional-fun).

It gets the output you're looking for:

```
0 Item #5
1 Item #4
3 Item #8
```

As the other answers point out, there are additional parameters to filter and map that get you half the way there.  To get all the way there, you need to do a first map to create a temporary structure that holds the original sequence of the item. Then filter. Then map again to make an array of the output you want before joining.  cool.

Here are the key changes:

`myFormatter` gets a second parameter that is the index of the element in the array

and it outputs an object:

```
{
   index: 0,
   item: theItem
}
```

So after the first map, we have an array of objects that contain the original index of the item in the original array and the item.  We can then filter which leaves us with an array of only the items that pass the filter.  The final map then creates the output you want by combining the original index in our temporary  structure with the output of the item in that structure.

```
class Item {
    constructor(itemNumber){
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }
    toString(){
        return "Item #" + this.itemNumber;
    }
}

function myFilter(element){
    return element.item.itemNumber > 3;
}

function myFormatter(item, index){
    return {index, item};
}

var listOfObjects = [];
listOfObjects.push(new Item(5));
listOfObjects.push(new Item(4));
listOfObjects.push(new Item(1));
listOfObjects.push(new Item(8));

// var output = formatArray(listOfObjects, myFilter, myFormatter);
const output = listOfObjects
  .map(myFormatter)
  .filter(myFilter)
  .map(e => `${e.index} ${e.item}`)
  .join("\n");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you for the response.  At first I thought the other answer was correct and it seemed simpler, but it wasn't correct.  The other answer didn't keep the original index numbers (and your answer does).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the syntax for Array.prototype.map():

```
var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

**Runnable Example**:

https://jsbin.com/bopodehaku/1/edit?js,console

**Mozilla Reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example

Comment: This isn't quite correct.  The output that is produced doesn't have the indexes of the original array correctly, because the filter changed the array, so the other answer (which first does a map to keep the original index) is the correct answer.  But thank you for the response.
```
0 Item #5
1 Item #4
2 Item #8
```
But it should be:
```
0 Item #5
1 Item #4
3 Item #8"
```